# Trying to understand Haagerup tensor product $B(H)\otimes_{\rm h}B(K)$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

I’m self reading Haagerup tensor product of operator spaces. Understanding it properly, I’m trying some examples. Let $H$ And $K$ be Hilbert space. Let $B(H)$ and $K(H)$ denotes the spaces of bounded and compact operators on $H$?

> Can someone explain me what is $B(H)\otimes_{\rm h}B(K)$ and  $B(H)\otimes_{\rm h}K(H)$? Are these spaces completely isometric to some well known operator space?

Is there any reference/lecture notes where I can find these kind of stuff?

P.S: The same question was first asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097773/trying-to-understand-haagerup-tensor-product-bh-otimes-rm-hbk).

Comment: You ask for a reference or lecture notes.  But where did you come across these ideas?  Knowning that might help people to give references which agree with your interests/motivation.

Comment: @MatthewDaws: I'm reading Haagerup tensor product from Effros-Ruan's operator space book but this book does not seem to answer what I asked here.

Answer (score 6):

When $H,K$ are finite dimensional, this is well explained in Pisier's book *Introduction to operator space theory* in the chapter on Haagerup tensor product, and your space is just the completely bounded maps on $B(K,H)$. When $H$ and $K$ are infinite dimensional, the argument works identically with bounded operators replaced by compact operators. To obtain a similar identification for bounded operators, my guess is that it is better to work with larger completions (extended Haagerup tensor product).

Let me expand a bit. When $H,K$ are finite dimensional, $B(K,H) = H_c \otimes_h K^*_{r}$ (where $H_c$ denotes $H$ with the column operator space structure, and $K^*_r$ denotes $K^*$ with the row Hilbert space structure, the dual of $K_c$). More generally, $H_c\otimes_h \cdot = H_c \otimes_{min} \cdot$ and $\cdot \otimes_{h} H_r = \cdot \otimes_{min} H_r$: when one tensorizes on the left (resp. right) by column (resp. row) operator spaces, Haagerup and minimal tensor product coincide. Taking the dual, we obtain $B(K,H)^* = H^*_r \otimes_h K_c$.

Combining all this with the associativity of the Haagerup tensor product, we obtain the natural identifications
$$ B(H) \otimes_h B(K) = H_c \otimes_h (H_r^* \otimes_h K_c)\otimes_h K^*_r = H_c \otimes_{min} K^*_r \otimes_{min} B(H,K)^* = B(H,K) \otimes_{min} (B(K,H))^* = CB(B(K,H),B(K,H)).$$
For example, when $H=K=\mathbf{C}^n$, we obtain
$$ M_n \otimes_h M_n = M_n(S^1_n) = CB(M_n,M_n).$$